# mongodb aggregation query to include a specific field

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb schema which looks like

```
{
post_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "Post"
},
comment_by: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "User"
},
comment: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
parent_comment_id: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Comment"
},
is_deleted: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
}
```

}

I want to group the comments such that
they have common "parent_comment_id" but I also want to include the "comment" field of the
document whose "id" is "parent_comment_id".
This is query I have written

```
var comments = await Comment.aggregate([
        {
            "$match": {
                post_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(post_id)
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                _id: `$parent_comment_id`,
                replies: { "$count": {} }
            }
        }
    ])
```

and the result is

```
{ _id: new ObjectId("6278e11fa7887263e6e6fada"), replies: 3 },
{ _id: new ObjectId("6278fb9f6a8d30c46eb53a84"), replies: 5 },
{ _id: null, replies: 2 }
```

Result I want

```
{ _id: new ObjectId("6278e11fa7887263e6e6fada"), replies: 3 , comment : <comment>},
{ _id: new ObjectId("6278fb9f6a8d30c46eb53a84"), replies: 5 , comment : <comment>},
```

Comment: Please provide sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome heeya joshi!.

You can do something like this:

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {post_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(post_id)}
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          parent_comment_id: {$ifNull: ["$parent_comment_id", "$_id"]}
        }
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: "$parent_comment_id",
          "comment": {
            $push: {
              $cond: [
                {$eq: ["$parent_comment_id", "$_id"]},
                "$comment",
                "$$REMOVE"
              ]
            }
          },
          replies: {"$count": {}}
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          comment: {$arrayElemAt: ["$comment", 0]},
          replies: 1
        }
      }
    ])
```

As you can see [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-PsfTlnsWzE).

After your `$match`, the `addFields` adds the `parent_comment_id` to the parents themselves. Then the `$group` keeps the comment only for the parents.